# Compare two columns ( string formats) in two data frames while length of columns is not the same

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare

The followings are two data frames:
Data frame A:

```
index  codes     
1        A      
2        B    
3        C
4        D
```

Data frame B

```
index    cym
1         A
2         L
3         F
4         B
5         N
6         X
```

The length of A and B is not equal. I want to compare column "codes" (data frame A) with column "cym" (data frame B) and return the difference between these two columns plus the data in index column of data frame B. Output is like this:

```
index    cym
2        L
3        F
5        N
6        X
```

I tried to solve it using merge and equals functions. But I could not generate the output.

Comment: I check your last question and what if there are 3 consecutives NaNs? Or there are only 2 or 1 NaNs like in sample, never 3,4 or more consecutive NaNs? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `isin`:

```
B[~B.cym.isin(A.codes)]

#index  cym
#1   2    L
#2   3    F
#4   5    N
#5   6    X
```

Answer (score 3):

The more verbose but faster version of @Psidom's answer.

```
mask = ~np.in1d(B.cym.values, A.codes.values)
pd.DataFrame(
    B.values[mask],
    B.index[mask],
    B.columns
)

  index cym
1     2   L
2     3   F
4     5   N
5     6   X
```

---

***Timing***

```
%timeit B[~B.cym.isin(A.codes)]
1000 loops, best of 3: 348 µs per loop

%%timeit
mask = ~np.in1d(B.cym.values, A.codes.values)
pd.DataFrame(
    B.values[mask],
    B.index[mask],
    B.columns
)
10000 loops, best of 3: 194 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 3):

For sake of completeness:

```
In [22]: B.query("cym not in @A.codes")
Out[22]:
   index cym
0      2   L
1      3   F
2      5   N
3      6   X
```